# Creating SPA, using templates and ajax

Tags: asp.net, single-page-application

I've just started with ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms and I want to try create a really simple SPA - contacts application, the purpose is to enable the client to add / remove contacts and watch them.

So I've thought about what I need to this application, but I don't know if it exists in ASP.NET. Actually I need two templates which I can switch between them whenever I want to and manipulate data using AJAX. Additional part - I use only jQuery - not MVC framework.

**My questions are:**

1. Are there templates in Web Forms? I heard about something inside 'Ajax Control Toolkit' but I don't want to use any external code (only jQuery as external code). As I said before, I want to include in the page two templates which I can switch between them and manipulate data when I get data from the ajax requests.
2. While I want to remove / add / get data, where do the ajax requests go to? should I create a web service which handle this requests? are there another options?

Comment: I suggest you break this up into 2 questions, and make the title more clear.  Also, wtf are you asking

Comment: By mistake I wrote Win Forms in line 10 instead of Web Forms, I don't think I should separate it to two questions.

Answer (score 0):

1: No, webforms is a server/client intensive process which invalidates the whole premise of SPA where server interaction is kept to a minimum and most data is sent down on the initial request.

2: Yes any webservices can be used for SPA in Ajax.

Comment: If I use webservices, how does the validation works? Without ajax I just created a validation control which validate both client and server side, is there an option to do that in webservices?